# Property defined in Objective C file not visible in Swift (same target)

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I have a `DataStore` class defined in Objective C. It has a `controller` property of type `Controller` (class defined in Swift). Both classes are in the same target `Foo`. When I try to access the `controller` property inside a class `Baz`, I get an error:

> Value of type 'DataStore' has no member 'controller'

`Baz` is written in Swift and is in the same target `Foo`.

`DataStore.m` (target `Foo`)

```
#import <Foo/Foo-Swift.h>
@interface DataStore ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) Controller *controller;
@end
```

`DataStore.h` (target `Foo`)

```
@class Controller;
@interface DataStore: NSObject
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) Controller *controller;
@end
```

`Controller.swift` (target `Foo`)

```
@objc(NHController)
public class Controller: NSObject {
  //
}
```

`Baz.swift` (target `Foo`, used be another target)

```
class Bar {
   func test() {
     let dataStore = DataStore()
     dataStore.controller // compiler error
   }
}
```

I tried cleaning and building a dozen times. I tried clearing derived data but that didn't do anything. I just moved `Bar` to the `Foo` target. I had no problem accessing the properties of `DataStore` before (when `Baz` was in another target.)

Comment: Have you added `#import "DataStore.h"` in bridging header?

Comment: @ChanchalChauhan yes, the error is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was related to circular references between Swift and Objective-C: https://cjwirth.com/tech/circular-references-swift-objc

Updating `Controller.swift` fixed it:

```
public typealias Controller = NHController

@objc public class NHController: NSObject {
  //
}
```